# No puedo utilizar mi key generada por token (incorrecto)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, net, jsonwebtoken

estoy intentando generar token para mis servicios, el cual ya me genera pero al momento de utilizar mi Token-Bearer vía postman me dice que la llave es incorrecta.

Estoy utilizando net.core 6.0

***www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="The signature is invalid"***

```csharp
var jwt = _configuration.GetSection("Jwt").Get<Jwt>();
    
var claims = new[]
{
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, jwt.Subject),
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),
    new Claim("id", _BE_Usuarios.CO_USUA)
};
    
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwt.Key));
var singIn = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
    
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                jwt.Issuer,
                jwt.Audience,
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60)
);

return new
{
    TOKEN = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token)
};
```

He definido la siguiente configuración en el archivo `Program.cs`

```csharp
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };
});
```

Comment: Prueba a poner el token y la clave de firma en jwt.io y comprobar si valida la firma, así como los claims que contiene el token.

Comment: Me devuelve -Invalid Signature- los claims si está pero la key no lo reconoce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el constructor de `JwtSecurityToken` falta incluir la credencial de firma (`singIn`, que deberías renombrar a algo como `signingKey`), con lo que está utilizando una por defecto. [Documentación pertinente](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytoken.-ctor?view=msal-web-dotnet-latest#system-identitymodel-tokens-jwt-jwtsecuritytoken-ctor(system-string-system-string-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-security-claims-claim))-system-nullable((system-datetime))-system-nullable((system-datetime))-microsoft-identitymodel-tokens-signingcredentials)). Pásale el quinto parámetro `signIn` a dicho constructor, y debería funcionar correctamente.

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo!